# Why does a number inside parentheses have methods, but a number outside parentheses does not?

Tags: javascript, primitive

In the JavaScript console, if I execute:

`2.toString()`

I get the error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

But if I execute `(2).toString()`, the result is `"2"`.

Why do I have to use the parentheses in order to apply methods from the Number prototype?

Other "primitives" work without parentheses. For example:

`true.toString()` => `"true"`

`"".toString()` => `""`

It doesn't work for `null` or `undefined`, of course, since by definition they don't have any properties or methods.

Why is Number different from Boolean and String in this way?

Comment: I bet on parser ambiguity. Dot in `2.toString()` is treated as decimal separator, but is not followed by a digit. Hence the error.

Comment: @MarkReed You're right--thanks, my initial search didn't turn up that question.